# File explorer with behavior like Windows when you type

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, thunar

Is there a file explorer (or a way to get one of the famous file explorers e.g. Nautilus, Thunar) to behave like Windows when you type in a file name?

The behavior in Windows when you type a file name is that it scrolls to the file starting with what you just typed, the difference is there is a timeout for that and if it times out and you start typing again it acts like it never received anything, Nautilus and Thunar keep what you wrote forever and you have to erase/correct etc.

Comment: In Nautilus, you can press Esc to start typing a new filename

Comment: I think I can make that happen. I'll write a script, will post in couple days

Comment: @Serg thanks for the initiative, I think this confirms that nothing already exists?

Comment: I don't think so. At least those file managers that are build with Gtk toolkit, should exhibit same behavior as Nautilus.